# Replacement solution for burglar bars for externally hinged casement windows (shutters or similar)

Tags: windows, security, shutters

Burglar bars are pretty common here, in Indonesia. I have some on my bedroom window. However I really hate them and want to remove them.

[image]

Here is the inside for comparison

[image]

I would still like to have some sort of visual deterrent against burglary.

Note that in the photo there is also a ventilation in the middle, which I don't like either as it's a dust trap and too 'busy'. I already removed a similar smaller one by cutting through the window frame and replacing one hinged window and the ventilation area with just a pane of glass, and it's a big improvement.

In practical terms I suppose the shutters would be open most of the time, and closed when I'm not home. So it wouldn't be very ideal for them to take up a lot of space inside, because I'm going to put some low drawer units in front of the window, so it's likely that there would be 'stuff' in the way of frequently opening and closing these shutters.

OTOH if I install them on the exterior wall then I'm not sure how to secure them so they can't be opened, and also it seems like they might be a bit ugly/obtrusive if they are mostly open perpendicular (the current dimensions are roughly: 38cm - plastered brick; 4cm window frame; 68cm - hinged window unit; 41cm louvred section; ditto 68, 4, 38)

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I can do to more-or-less fix this? (note: in general windows will be closed, to keep mosquitoes out)

Answer (score 1):

Polycarbonate panels are probably what you want.  They can be unbreakable,so will replace burglary bars.

They look like glass so you can see out without any bars in place.

Will need to use google to find them near you.  Usually used for security.

Comment: With all the plexiglass that's been used to put up barriers between people over the last 2 years, it will probably be _extremely_ expensive. Yes, that's different from polycarbonate, but I can only imagine the prices have climbed at the same rate, and poly was ---probably--- more expensive than plex in the first place. This is a great answer (has my vote), just a warning for the OP.

Comment: I did think of that but I suppose the thing I like about the burglar bars is they say 'go away', which I'm not sure that unbreakable glass (or plastic) does - what you don't want is someone having a bang on your expensive unbreakable window, and damaging it, or even perhaps using that as an invitation to break in elsewhere.

Comment: I see from Google you can actually replace the metal bars with polycarbonate ones like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdYL2vlhv0k They are relatively inexpensive (but probably not available here) but have the drawback of, er, still being bars on the windows (albeit mostly transparent ones)

Answer (score 0):

fixed external bars and sliding windows (often with mosquito-proof) mesh this combination is popular in
Australia

[image]

Comment: Not quite clear from the photo but it looks like that security mesh (?) is fixed in place? I'm looking to get more like an unobstructed pane of glass that I can look out of , iyswim

Comment: You probably would want polycarbonate panels.  Should be unbreakable, but will require replacing your glass window panes with them.  Can google unbreakable glass for more information.

Comment: Mosquito-proof mesh probably has a 2-inch wide opening.  *cancels trip to Australia*

Comment: LOL.  the 2 inch mesh is an expanded aluminium mesh intended to stop burglars. there is a finer mesh also installed to stop insects